# How do I right justify data in react-table columns?

Tags: reactjs, react-table

I have these columns defined in a bit of Node code to create columns in a react table:

```
const columns = [{
    Header: 'Regiom',
    accessor: 'region' // String-based value accessors!
  }, {
    Header: 'Division',
    accessor: 'division'
  }, {
    Header: 'File Client Id',
    accessor: 'facilityid'
  }, {
    Header: 'Meter #',
    accessor: 'meternumber'
  }, {
    Header: 'Service Address',
    accessor: 'serviceaddress'
  }, {
    Header: 'Service City',
    accessor: 'servicecity'
  }, {
    Header: 'Service Zip',
    accessor: 'servicezip'
  }, {
    Header: 'Account Number',
    accessor: 'accountnumber'
  }, {
    Header: 'Utility Provider',
    accessor: 'utilityprovider'
  }, {
    Header: 'Interval Start',
    accessor: 'intervalstart'
  }, {
    Header: 'Interval End',
    accessor: 'intervalend'
  }, {
    Header: 'kWh Usage',
    accessor: 'kwh_usage'
  }, {
    Header: 'kW Demand',
    accessor: 'kw_demand'
  }, {
    Header: 'Gas Unit of Measure',
    accessor: 'gas_uom'
  }, {
    Header: 'Gas Usage Amount',
    accessor: 'gas_usage_amount'
  }];
```

All I really want to do is leave the column headers centered but right justify the numbers - like, for example, the kWh Usage column. How do I do that? Is there a way to apply a style to a column within this? I tried the style: {text-align: right} and the code throws syntax errors...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do it via adding custom component in `Header` or `Cell`.

```
const columns = [
  {
    Header: () => <div style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>Regiom</div>,
    accessor: "region",
    Cell: row => <div style={{ textAlign: "right" }}>{row.value}</div>
  },
  ...
  ...
```

Here is the sample code for you.
https://codesandbox.io/s/react-table-simple-table-eep26

Hope this will work for you!

Comment: Wow... This works and do you know what I had wrong, as far as I can see? I've been trying this type of thing for an hour and when you wrote this, I saw it...

I wrote cell:... As opposed to Cell:... Capital "C" as opposed to lowercase.

Answer (score 2):

Solution here: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#example

```
{
    Header: 'Age',
    accessor: 'age',
    Cell: props => <span className='number'>{props.value}</span> // Custom cell components!
  },
```

This link may be helpful to you: https://codeburst.io/4-four-ways-to-style-react-components-ac6f323da822

Answer (score 0):

add an attribute `center: true,`
so your code will be something like:

```
{
    Header: 'Age',
    accessor: 'age',
    center: true,
    Cell: props => <span className='number'>{props.value}</span> // Custom cell components!
  },
```

You can also add `right:true` to align your column's content to right